# How to share an interactive demo of an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working on an iOS app project at the moment (on Xcode using SwiftUI). Once it's done, I'd like to be able to share an interactive version of the app on an iPhone simulator online, so that people can test and play around with the app remotely (without needing to download and compile anything themselves).

Is anyone aware of a way of doing this? I suspect it would require an online compiler and iPhone simulator.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Testflight.

Comment: Thanks, Gereon - unfortunately, the project I'm working on is very time pressured (e.g. once I finish coding, I will need to have an interactive demo launched in the next few hours) and so I won't have time to wait for the app to pass beta app review (as required for TestFlight). I ideally would also like to provide access to anyone regardless of whether they have provided an email address and been granted access to a beta program.

Comment: Testflight works via anonymous links, if you want. Also, you can do the initial beta review as soon as you have your first working screen. There will be no further reviews if you then don't change the version number, but only increment the build.

Comment: Okay, thank you - I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

You could generate an .ipa file and send it around, but it's a pain to get it set up. You need the UDID of each device that you plan to install it to, an ad-hoc provisioning profile that all those UDIDs are registered to, and then they'd still need Xcode to install it to their device (via Devices and Simulators, they can drag and drop the .ipa file).

Here's a more in-depth step-by-step instruction on that: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev7ccaf4d3c

Really, testflight is the most scalable solution since you only need everyone's emails, and it will force you to get a similar distribution pipeline which you'd need for the appstore anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation wilc0, I'll have a look into those.